# Is it possible to declare a column of table as not ' ' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have already tried the following code:

```
use college;
CREATE TABLE student(
      Name char(40) not '',
   );
```

but this code gives an error:

> 'Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''', )' at line 2.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, using `CHECK` constraint and not equal operator:

```
CREATE TABLE student(
      Name char(40)  CHECK (Name != '')
);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=beeb61b2ad8f1c78e27bcc07c86b5947)**

Comment: For me, this is something the application should take care of. To put the check into the database reduces its insert and update performance but has no advantages because the application has to check if the insert was successful and if not place the corresponding error. So it can do this before insert as well

Comment: One must remember that this constraint **allows** NULL value in the column.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff *this is something the application should take care of.* This is data integrity check which **must** be checked on DBMS level. From this point of view there is no difference between this constraint and any other constraint type (uniqueness, foreign key and so on). Formally, you can check them at the application level - but you won't do that, will you?

Comment: What does it help you if you do not allow an empty string for a name column? What is the advantage? It makes sense to do not allow null but everything else? A name ‚?‘ is senseless too. Will you Check on That also? And on every other entry which is not a name? So you need a table with all valid names and check against it... you understand what I mean?